# C++ read Registry

Tags: c++, windows, registry, npapi, registrykey

i try to read the Registry in my NPAPI-Plugin:

```
bool ScriptablePluginObject::Invoke(NPObject* obj, NPIdentifier methodName, const NPVariant* args, uint32_t argCount, NPVariant* result) {
    ScriptablePluginObject *thisObj = (ScriptablePluginObject*) obj;
    char* name                      = npnfuncs->utf8fromidentifier(methodName);
    LPCWSTR game_path               = getRegKey(L"SOFTWARE\\World of RPG", L"Path");

    MessageBox(NULL, game_path, L"Debugging", MB_TOPMOST);

    /* ... */
}

LPCWSTR ScriptablePluginObject::getRegKey(LPCWSTR location, LPCWSTR name) {
    HKEY hKey;
    LPBYTE folder   = new BYTE[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD dwSize    = sizeof(folder);
    long registry   = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, location, 0, KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hKey);
    long entry      = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, name, NULL, REG_NONE, folder, &dwSize);

    if(registry != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        return L"Error1";
    }

    if(entry != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        return L"Error2";
    }

    RegCloseKey(hKey);
    folder[dwSize / sizeof(folder[0])] = '\0';
    return (LPCWSTR) folder;
}
```

But it's returned every call `Error2`. I've tried a lot of changes:

- change the Path (with Start and/or Ending `\\`)
- change parameters

I Want to get the Path of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\World of RPG\Path`:

[image]

Anyone can help me? What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try checking the actual [return value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to see why it failed. If you don't examine the return value, you can't see why it didn't return `ERROR_SUCCESS`. It returns other values, and those values have meaning, but the meaning only matters if you **actually look at it** to see what it contains. Your code as written currently says "If it doesn't return success, show me some meaningless text that says ErrorX." Instead, save the return value, and check that saved value against `ERROR_SUCCESS`.

Comment: I'm really new on C++. I've tried to convert the long value to LPCWSTR to print it out on the message box. But it's not working: http://pastebin.com/1Q2F3JMp

Comment: Converting a numeric to a string is a pretty standard task, and has nothing to do with the Windows API or the registry. If you can't perform that task, perhaps you're not quite ready to try writing a NPAPI plugin. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/D9j2Nwbp/) for some information about doing that conversion - I found it using `cplusplus integer to string` in Google.

Comment: What OS are you using? `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` on Windows 8 may require administrator privileges. You should ask for as little permissions as necessary. If you only try to read the key, use `KEY_READ` instead.

Comment: @KenWhite I've try to learn currently C++. Coming from Java/PHP. I Know that are basics but everyone has to start somewhere.

Comment: Currently i'm using `Windows 7 64bit`. Have replaced to `KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_64KEY`. Yet the second method (`RegQueryValueEx`) will not work. Question-Source edited.

Comment: Are your plugin and "World of RPG" both 32-bit (or both 64-bit) binaries? If they're different (one's 32-bit, the other's 64-bit) you'll have to use registry redirection to get the right registry.

Comment: The Binary or the Software of "World of RPG" is not relevant. Im only need to **read** the Path in the Registry. Have the entrys in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\World of RPG\Path` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\World of RPG\Path`

Comment: @AdrianPreuss Also - I know you're learning C++ - but your code is not very well done. You shouldn't call an API function when a previous (related) API call failed. Plus the way you're doing memory allocation is suspect.

Comment: @xxbbcc `when a previous (related) API call failed` Uhm, nope! I've minimize the source (have posted only relevant lines). **see the** `/* ... */` in the source.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss Give me a minute, I'll post you a sample. Have to type it up / compile first.

Comment: Okay. I've compile directly and testing it. Closing Chrome, build on Visual Studio, and restart Chrome (Have add the `.dll` directly to my build directory). I Know that the NPAPI is **deprecated** in Chrome!

Comment: @AdrianPreuss I posted that sample for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `getRegKey()`, your `folder` variable is a pointer, so `sizeof(folder)` is 4 (if compiling for 32bit) or 8 (if compiling for 64bit).  Thus `RegQueryValueEx()` fails with an `ERROR_MORE_DATA` error code.

You are also using the wrong data type for the array.  You need to use `WCHAR` instead of `BYTE`.

Change this:

```
LPBYTE folder   = new BYTE[MAX_PATH];
DWORD dwSize    = sizeof(folder);
```

To this:

```
LPWSTR folder   = new WCHAR[MAX_PATH];
DWORD dwSize    = sizeof(WCHAR) * MAX_PATH;
```

With that said, you are leaking the memory pointed to by `folder`, since you never `delete[]` it.

Comment: Awesome! Okay, see the problem. C++ is hard for newcomer if you only using little languages like Java or PHP :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's the sample I mentioned in the comments above:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

LSTATUS ReadRegistry ( LPCWSTR sPath, LPCWSTR sKey, LPWSTR pBuffer, DWORD *pBufferSize );

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

    WCHAR sBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; // 2048 bytes
    DWORD nBufferSize = BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof ( WCHAR );

    ZeroMemory ( sBuffer, nBufferSize );
    LSTATUS nResult = ReadRegistry ( L"SOFTWARE\\7-Zip", L"Path64",
        sBuffer, &nBufferSize );

    // check nResult for ERROR_SUCCESS to know if the call succeeded or not

    return 0;
}

LSTATUS ReadRegistry ( LPCWSTR sPath, LPCWSTR sKey, LPWSTR pBuffer, LPDWORD pBufferSize )
{
    HKEY hKey;
    LSTATUS nResult = ::RegOpenKeyEx ( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sPath,
        0, KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hKey );

    if ( nResult == ERROR_SUCCESS )
    {
        nResult = ::RegQueryValueEx ( hKey, sKey, NULL, NULL,
            (LPBYTE) pBuffer, pBufferSize );

        RegCloseKey ( hKey );
    }

    return ( nResult );
}
```

Notice how the `ReadRegistry` function doesn't allocate memory - it takes a buffer and fills it with data. It's a lot easier to deal with memory if you always have the caller allocate memory. If the callee allocates memory, the caller may not know how memory was allocated and it may not know how to free it. (Of course, you can always assume the use of `new` and `delete` but things are simpler if only one side does this consistently. If the caller allocates memory, it'll know how to free it. The callee only needs to put data in the allocated space.

Also, notice how the return value of the API functions is checked before proceeding to the next call - this is important because this tells you if you got a useful registry handle back or not and whether you need to close it or not.

(This sample is really just C, not C++ but it still applies.)